# Send notification through Azure Notification Hub in new Portal

Tags: azure-notificationhub

How to use 'test send' tile/option in the Azure Notification hub. Where to add the Registration ID/ Token ID in the Portal. How to use it. Please suggest me some articles on this. Here is the exact picture

[image]

I just started using Notification hub. I don't prior experience on push notifications or azure notification service.

Answer (score 1):

When you register device on azure push notification service - it creates new entity on its notification hub.

This entity has 3 main fields: registrationId, deviceTokens and tags.
Test send works with tokens. Tokens are just like tags in Instagram or Stackoverflow. You can pass there something like user name and send on all user devices by one send.
Also you can pass device token in tag, or regId. So you can test send test notification on selected device.

P.S. Best way to work with azure services: Visual Studio. You can connect your azure hub, watch the list of your registered devices (regId, deviceToken, tokens and expiration dates(you can not do it in azure console)) (also you can use test send by VS)

Comment: hey thanks, But where to add registration-id,Tokens and tags? Is there any way to add these details in the azure/VS directly.

Comment: you can edit tokens in Visual studio.
Just open VS > Server Explorer > Azure > Enter Your Azure Account credentials > Hubs >
In device registrations table you can see all registered devices and edit token of any record)

Comment: Ou. Maybe I don't really understand your last question.
To use push notifications you have to register your device on notification hub. You can register from device, using SDK, or send device token on backend and register using azure api:
https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj927170.aspx